# Eliminating white space in ajax search

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I've created an ajax search box using the keyup function to find profiles in my database.

```
$('#asearch').keyup(function(){
    var search_term = $(this).val();
```

The problem I'm having is that in my search box once I hit the space bar after typing the first name my page is no longer populated with results. Looking to make it so I can search a first name enter a space and a last name and still have results.

```
if (isset($_POST['search_term'])){
    $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['search_term']));


    if (!empty($search_term)){

        $search = mysql_query("SELECT `firstname`, `lastname` FROM `tempusers`
        WHERE `firstname` LIKE '%$search_term%'");
        $result_count = mysql_num_rows($search);

        while ($results_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($search)) {
            echo  '<li>', $results_row['firstname'],'  ', $results_row['lastname'], '</li></br>';
        }
    }

}
```

Tried using a regex `$search_term = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $search_term);` but it did not work like I was hoping it would. Any tips one may have will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function:

> Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a
>   string.

Plugging it into your code:

```
$search_term = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_POST['search_term'])));
```

By the way, is there a reason that you are using htmlentities on input?

Comment: Was using htmlentites for extra protection, what would you suggest  using?

Comment: @Octavius htmlentities will only help protect against XSS. You should only really use it when you're outputting user-generated data to the screen. If you're wanting to ensure that your database is secure from SQL injection, you should use prepared statements w/ the PDO object or mysqli.

Answer (score 2):

Like Blam said before sometimes is needed to split search string.
I am often using this kind of approach:

```
$search_term = str_replace(' ','%', trim($search_term));
//"paul dyk" will be changed to "paul%dyk"
//% will match any charackers between those you need. So if you need filter out those names like "pauladyk juk" use $search_term = str_replace(' ',' % ', trim($search_term)); as then spaces must exist, but there can be any words between them.

$search = mysql_query("SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',firstname, lastname) as full_name FROM tempusers WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ',firstname, lastname) LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_term)."%'");
//I would use concat_ws to join strings so if one of them is NULL it will not matter. Using concate with NULL you get no result

while ($results_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($search)) {
            echo  '< li>' . $results_row['full_name'].  '</ li>< br>';
        }
```

Comment: I really appreciate you taking time out to explain that, thanks!

Comment: That's a nice approach if you are sure that users enter their search terms in the correct order. It's faster than my example. BTW: Didn't know that CONCAT_WS() function. Learning new stuff every day :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with a "side comment":

You are just looking into the firstname column in your select query. One way to find "firstname lastname" might be to modify your search:

```
$search = mysql_query("SELECT firstname, lastname FROM tempusers
    WHERE CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) LIKE '%$search_term%'");
```

So if you want to find anything in the lastname you need to look there, too.

Then back to the search query:

What I usually do first is split the query into "tokens". I do that to make sure that I can also find - for example "lastname firstname" and similar queries (for example people might enter "paul dyk" and still want to find "paul van dyk").

A simple way of doing so is by using explode(' ', $search_term), which will work as long as your users behave. Another option would be the regex you mentioned in your question.

Then use these "subqueries" to search your database.

explode() will give you an array of words.

```
array(
   'paul',
   'van',
   'dyk'
)
```

From there you need to build your SQL query:

```
// DON'T DO THE ESCAPE THING BEFORE THIS!
$words = explode(' ', $search_term)

$sql = 'SELECT `firstname`, `lastname` FROM `tempusers` WHERE 1 = 1';

for ($words as $word) {
   if (!empty($word)) {
     $word = mysql_real_escape_string($word);
     $sql .= " AND (firstname LIKE '%" . $word . "%' OR lastname LIKE '%" . $word . "%')";
   }
}

$search = mysql_query($sql);
```

That will build a query where it will search for each word "one by one" and not in a specific order. It's a bit slower, though.

Comment: Thank you for going out your way and teaching me. I really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#asearch').keyup(function(){
    var search_term = this.value.trim();
});
```

or if insisiting on jQuery

```
$('#asearch').keyup(function(){
    var search_term = $.trim($(this).val());
});
```

will trim away whitespace at the end/beginning before the value is sent serverside.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the client doing cleaning up my input data, even if it's just a trim(). You can do that as an additional step - and probably it alone would be enough in this case (we're talking AJAX, so JavaScript is required anyway). But it's always better to have your server side fix all input - just to be sure.